# Is this optimal schedule task NPC?

Tags: scheduling, np-complete

I volunteered to write a program to schedule parent-teacher conferences. The principal wants parents to select 3 possible datetimes to visit their english *and* math teacher (at the same time).

Once all the parents have selected 3 datetimes, I'm supposed to figure out the optimal way to schedule the parent-teacher conferences so the greatest number of parents can meet with *both* teachers.

(If there is a time conflict and the math teacher can't be at the conference, a parent will only meet with the english teacher)

I don't know much about NP type problems, but when I hear the word "optimal" and "schedule" together, I start to wonder...

I already told the principal I couldn't do that, but I wanted to know if it was NP complete. And if it is, assuming there are:

- 500 parents
- 15 english teachers
- 5 math teachers
- 25 datetimes to pick from

could this be solved correctly in a few seconds, minutes or hours on your grandma's computer?

Comment: Given the limited number of datetimes available (25) I don't see that this needs be a particularly troublesome problem - even if you have to work through the 2^20 combinations of teachers that are possible for each datetime.  Getting an optimal solution seems NP to me - but I would expect that this can still be computed in minutes rather than years.

Comment: My gut feeling is that this is NP-hard but computable in reasonable time. This assuming that these are not one-to-one conferences in which case there is obviously no solution. This is an interesting puzzle, likely more to come as I fiddle with it.

Comment: I'm assuming that the number of parents attending a session (datetime) is not space-constrained which is likely not true in the real world. I'm also expecting a highly non-uniform selection of preferred sessions, which I do expect to obtain.

Comment: Giving every parent their first preference made for some very busy teachers with a maximum conference size of about 4 or 5 parents, but it is satisfiable and only took 24 milliseconds to compute. I now have to decide which factor to minimize: parental schedule disappointment or teacher exhaustion.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have a partial answer to your question and a simulation that allows me to attempt different scenarios. Here are my working (but mutable) assumptions:

- The parameters are as you list them
- The choices of session times by parents follow a power law ([Benford's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford's_law) Distribution) as this models the expected non-uniformity of preferrences
- Depending upon the run, there were ~20 parents who were 'intransigent' and could only come at one session.
- Each English teacher has one and only one corresponding Math teacher, as their correlation is presumed high but I don't know how high. The code can handle any correlation coefficient from 0 to 1.
- The whole shebang from generating plausible simulated parents ('smith' .. 'atkins'), teachers, time selections, and satisfying results took 300 milliseconds on a midling machine (5300 [BogoMIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BogoMips)).

My second order optimizations didn't even kick in as the first pass allowed every parent's first choice to be accommodated with a maximum of 11 parents in one session. This result was sub-optimal for the teachers who had to attend about half the time slots with a mean parent group of ~3.

Given any expressed interest I can make the code available, as it is about 125 lines.

Comment: So did you find it was NP-something? And if you have the time, post the code someplace. I'd like to see it!

Comment: It was O(n) and more of the 0.3 seconds was spent constructing the scenario not solving it. Would you please tell me which of my assumptions (e.g. teachers attending 12ish sessions, singular mapping from English to Math teacher) should be relaxed to better model the situation? I'd prefer to post "interesting" code which is now rather boring.

Comment: The 1:1 mapping of English to Math teacher is the most unrealistic. Teachers attending ~12 sessions is acceptable.